# DOMpdf not saved in pc location

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I want to create pdf and want to force to save pdf in anywhere in PC automatically e.g. in browser's downloads folder but
Pdf file is saved in project folder, i don't know whats the problem. PHP code for pdf file generation is given as follows.

PHP CODE:

```
$pdf_content='
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>

            <style type="text/css">                         
                #pdf_header, #pdf_container{ border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px; }             
                #pdf_header{ margin:10px auto 0px; border-bottom:none; }                
                table{ width:580px; }               
                #pdf_container{margin:0px auto; }
                .rpt_title{ background:#99CCFF; }                                                           
            </style>

            <body>
            <div id="pdf_header" >
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr id="hdRow">
                <td width="20%"><img src="space_age_header.jpg" style="width:250px" ></td>              
                <td width="30%" align="center">Sample File</td>
                <td width="30%" align="left">Marimuthu<br>User Code : 179865420</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf_container" >
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="pink" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3"><b>Your Statement Summery</b></td> </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#006" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3" align="left">Your Heading.</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table> <tr> <td> Name </td><td> Department</td><td>Total </td><td>Grade </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Marimuthu </td><td> Admin</td><td>250 </td><td>A </td> </tr>          
            </div></body></html>';
            //$filename = 'app.pdf';
            //$reportPDF=createPDF(12, $pdf_content, 'activity_Report', $name );
    //function createPDF($pdf_userid, $pdf_content, $pdf_For, $filename){

    //$path='UsersActivityReports/';
    /*$rndNumber=rand();
    $filename=$pdf_userid.date("Ymd").$rndNumber.'.pdf';*/
    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('app.pdf', $output);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the PDF to save anywhere on a client machine, in case that's what you want to do (you might clarify your question). You can, however, send the PDF to the browser and indicate that you want a save dialog to pop up.

The PDF is saving to your project folder (on your server) because you are using the following:

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('app.pdf', $output);
```

[`$dompdf->output()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage) returns a string and [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) places the content of a string into a file on the *server* filesystem. And since you do not specify a path the file will be placed in the current working directory (e.g. where your script is located).

If you want to send the PDF to the client use `$dompdf->stream()`. Replace the two lines noted above with the following to have the browser show the save dialog:

```
$dompdf->stream('app.pdf');
```

Or, more explicitly

```
$dompdf->stream('app.pdf', array('Attachment' => true));
```

One final note. You can't use both the stream and output methods. If you want to both save the file to your server and send to the browser you would have to save the PDF, set the HTTP headers, then send the PDF to the browser:

```
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('app.pdf', $output);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($tmp, '8bit'));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=app.pdf);
echo $output;
```

(Headers taken from the [CPDF stream method](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.1/lib/class.pdf.php#L3092).)